# Template for landing pages

Tags: theme-development, themes, pages, templates

I'm using WP for a business site (not a blog) with landing pages. So there are no posts, only pages (actually, "landing pages") which I create with the Elementor page builder.

Since a typical theme has lots of unnecessary stuff for a landing page business site, I decided to create a lightweiht custom theme. I have a `header.php`, `footer.php` and basic css/js enqueued via `functions.php`. I want to create each page's content using a page builder.

I don't know what to put in `index.php`. This is something typical:

```php
<?php get_header(); ?>

// ....the wp loop goes here

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Of course in my case there is no loop - but that is where the main content goes. When I create a new page with Elementor (or other page builder, or Gutenberg), I want my custom per-page content to go in there, where the loop usually goes.

What markup do I place there, so the page builder knows where to insert each page's content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your theme folder. create a new php file.

For example call it: landingpage.php

in the php file you could have something as basic as:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Landing Page
*/
get_header();

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

 the_content();

endwhile;   

get_footer();

?>
```

Elementor will be called / inserted where it says the_content();

Included out of the box with elementor you should have a blank elementor template to choose from and using the built in elementor theme builder options create exactly what you are after also choosing conditions of when that page template gets used?

Comment: LOL the first thing I did was remove the loop, but I guess I really need it after all! Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem. Please see my edited part about elementor having a built in theme builder with a blank canvas option. Not sure if that is also an option for you but that depends on your theme.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I decided to create a custom theme anyway, because the average theme comes with LOTS of stuff I don't need, including js, css, fonts, emojis, ...... etc! So I want to use a very very simple theme (just jquery and bootstrap) and elementor. Thanks for showing me the way!

Comment: One more thing, why use `landingpage.php` instead of `index.php`? Why do you recommend doing it that way? (All pages on the site are landing pages) Is there a benefit from splitting it up like that?

Comment: index.php is not really used. it is only used to stop directory browsing from memory. page.php is actually the default index.php for pages

Comment: So if you customise page.php it makes ALL pages that dont specify a custom template use what ever you put in there.

Comment: So I should use `page.php` or `landingpage.php`?

Comment: if you want ALL pages that dont specify a custom template in the page options to use your custom theme then yes. if you only want a few specific pages to use that i would recommend leaving it as landingpage.php and manually choosing those pages to use the custom template "Landing Page".

Comment: Okay got it... Thanks again!